# How to do subtraction in strings

Tags: python, string, math, addition

How do you print addition in python?
I tried to  define addition and tell it to print:

`subtraction = int(number - reverse(number))
 print str(subtraction)`

But it always says:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Castor's Python Programs\proj02.py", line 16, in <module>
    subtraction = int(number - reverse(number))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

This is my full code:

```
import sys
def reverse(num):
        return (num)[::-1]

print "This is a puzzle favored by einstein. You will be asked to enter a three digit number, where the hundred's digit differs from the ones digit by at least two. The procedure will always yield 1089."
number = raw_input("Give me a number:")
print "For the number: "
print number
print " the reverse number is: "
print reverse(number)
print "The difference between "
print number
print" and "
print reverse(number)
print " is "
subtraction = int(number - reverse(number))
print  str(subtraction)
print "The reverse difference is: "
print  str(reverse(subtraction))
print "The sum of: "
print subtraction
print " and revDiff is: "
finaladdition = int(subtraction - reverse(subtraction))
print str(finaladdition)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Replace `subtraction = int(number - reverse(number))` with `subtraction = int(number) - int(reverse(number))`

Comment: You're trying to subtract a string when you're doing: `subtraction = int(number - reverse(number))`.  Try doing: `subtraction = int(number) - int(reverse(number))`.  Same with: `finaladdition = int(subtraction) - int(reverse(subtraction))`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to subtract two strings, which can't be done.  You want to convert those strings to numbers first before you perform the operations:

```
subtraction = int(number) - int(reverse(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `number` to a int before you subtract it. `number` here is a string confusingly, because it was set by `raw_input` which returns a string.

```
subtraction = int(number) - int(reverse(number))
```

For `print  str(reverse(subtraction))` to work `subtraction` must be converted to a string, because it is an int set by subtracting. Thus:

```
print  str(reverse(str(subtraction)))
```

But `reverse` will return a string so the str in front is unneeded.

```
print  reverse(str(subtraction))
```

Also, `finaladdition = int(subtraction - reverse(subtraction))` needs to become:

```
finaladdition = int(subtraction) - int(reverse(str(subtraction)))
```

We must convert `subtraction` to a string before passing it to `reverse`, because `reverse` uses it's argument as if it is a string. In the first part, `subtraction` is already a int so converting it to an int is unneeded.

Comment: Thank you soo much. I did have to add a few abs(), but your code helped a lot! This is my full code now